Trying to Stack 2 Columns into one Excel
I am currently attempting to combine two columns into one but have encountered an error that prevents me from completing this task. Additionally, the data from the second column appears to be pasting incorrectly after the error messages.
I would greatly appreciate any assistance with this issue.
=IF(P2<>"",P2,INDEX($R$2:$R$5000,ROW()-COUNTA($P$2:$P$5000)))

Column P and R contains formulas.


The general formula is as follows, you can adjust to your needs:
=IF(ROW() - 1 <= COUNTA(A:A)-1, INDEX(A:A, ROW()), INDEX(B:B, ROW() - COUNTA(A:A)+1))



Stacking Columns in Legacy Excel
In cell T2:
=IF((ROW()-ROW(P$2))<(ROWS(P$2:P$11)-COUNTBLANK(P$2:P$11)),
    INDEX(P$2:P$11,1+ROW()-ROW(P$2)),
    IF((ROW()-ROW(P$2))<(2*ROWS(P$2:P$11)-COUNTBLANK(P$2:P$11)-COUNTBLANK(R$2:R$11)),
        INDEX(R$2:R$11,1+ROW()-ROW(P$2)-ROWS(P$2:P$11)+COUNTBLANK(P$2:P$11)),""))


It is assumed that all cells have formulas and that the 'populated' cells are at the top of each column.


